# swapping values in different tables if the data exist then value + 1 if data = 0 then delete

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, swap

i have this table called **bag**:

```
+--------+----------+---------+----------+
| bag_id | chara_id | item_id | item_qty |
+--------+----------+---------+----------+
|      1 |        1 |       2 |       26 |
|      2 |        1 |       1 |       56 |
|      3 |        3 |       1 |        4 |
|      6 |        3 |       4 |        3 |
|      7 |        4 |       4 |        3 |
|      8 |        5 |       4 |        3 |
|      9 |        6 |       4 |        2 |
|     10 |        1 |       5 |        1 |
|     14 |        1 |       8 |        1 |
|     15 |        1 |       6 |        2 |
|     18 |        1 |       4 |        4 |
|     19 |        1 |       3 |        2 |
|     29 |        8 |       1 |        1 |
|     30 |        8 |       7 |        2 |
|     33 |        6 |       2 |        1 |
|     34 |        3 |       5 |        1 |
|     35 |        3 |       8 |        3 |
|     37 |        4 |       3 |        1 |
|     45 |        3 |       3 |       14 |
|     46 |        8 |       2 |        2 |
|     60 |        8 |       5 |        2 |
|     61 |        3 |       2 |       10 |
|     74 |       12 |       2 |        1 |
|     97 |       12 |       5 |        1 |
|    103 |        3 |       6 |        1 |
+--------+----------+---------+----------+
```

and have this table called **equipment**:

```
+----------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+---------+
| equip_id | chara_id | weapon_id | headgear_id | armor_id | ring_id |
+----------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+---------+
|        3 |        1 |         4 |           5 |        9 |       8 |
|        5 |        3 |         2 |           5 |        3 |       8 |
|        6 |        4 |         7 |           5 |        3 |       8 |
|        7 |        5 |         4 |           5 |        3 |       8 |
|        8 |        6 |         3 |           5 |        2 |       8 |
|       10 |        8 |         3 |           5 |        2 |       8 |
|       11 |        3 |         2 |           5 |        0 |       8 |
|       12 |        3 |         2 |           5 |        0 |       8 |
|       13 |       12 |         2 |           0 |        0 |       0 |
|       14 |        5 |         4 |           0 |        0 |       0 |
|       15 |        1 |         1 |           0 |        0 |       0 |
|       16 |        1 |         0 |           0 |        6 |       0 |
|       17 |        4 |         4 |           0 |        0 |       0 |
|       18 |        8 |         2 |           0 |        0 |       0 |
|       19 |        3 |         2 |           5 |        0 |       8 |
+----------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+---------+
```

**scenario:** 
player equips an item from the bag to equipment:

```
#unequipping:
1. if equipment id to be unequipped exist in the bag then that bag item = item + 1
   else
   insert that item to the bag

#equipping:   
1.  bag item = bag item - 1 where item_id = equipped item_id
    else if bag item = 0 then delete it.
```

basically i want to swap the item's from the equipment to the bag table,
though the twist is the quantity, wherein if that item to be swapped is already existing in the bag table then + 1 to the quantity and if the item from the bag table is = 1 then remove that item from the table and equip that item to the equipment table.

please pm me if you couldn’t understand my situation, its driving me nuts!

```
this is my current code(if it helps a little):

$fieldnames   = array(1=>'weapon', 'armor', 'ring', 'headgear');

        if (isset($fieldnames[$equip->item_type])) {
            $field = $fieldnames[$equip->item_type].'_id';

            $sql_unequip  = "INSERT INTO bag(item_id, chara_id, item_qty)VALUES(:item_id, :chara_id, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE item_qty = item_qty + 1";
            $sql_equip    = "UPDATE equipment SET $field   = :item_id WHERE chara_id = :chara_id";
            $sql_unequip2 = "DELETE FROM bag WHERE item_id = :item_id AND chara_id   = :chara_id AND item_qty = 0";


        }
```

Comment: Are you struggling with the algorithmic part of the problem, or coding it in PHP, or coding it in SQL?

Comment: @Patashu both, but i do think its more on the sql part

Comment: The `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` looks good, provided that you have defined a `UNIQUE` key over `(item_id, chara_id)` on the `bag` table.  The `equipment` table looks a bit wonky though, especially in light of the `SET $field` bit of the `UPDATE` statement... perhaps schema needs normalising?

Comment: @ eggyal it is already normalized.